# React-Native iOS hot reloading and debug mode not working in real device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**Background:**

I am working on a react-native app for a while and it was working fine till now. Currently facing some issues in the iOS on the same version that has been completely tested and verified before.

**Issue:**

Currently live reloading, hot reloading and even debug mode doesn't seem to work for my app. The app runs only for the first time, it wouldn't work if I try to relaunch the app from Xcode.

It stops at the splash screen always so I have to completely delete the app from the device and redeploy it from Xcode. I don't know what is causing this issue. It seems working fine on other laptops so I doubt the problem is with my Xcode.

This issue is not project-related as I have created a new app to test it out and experiencing the same outcome.
Could anyone help me with this?

Please read the things I have already tried before answering with some common things. Thank you in advance.

**Few things I have tried:**

- Cleaned the project.
- Cleaned the Xcode Derived Data
- Deleted the watchman cache.
- Updated Xcode, iPhone, and watchman to the latest version
- Pods re-installed.

**Reason for Issue:**

Version mismatch for iOS device and Xcode. iOS version: 14.6 and Xcode version 12.5 as Xcode 12.6 is not released yet is there any workaround?

Comment: Firstly, i think you need to improve the way you question things. Try not to put into paragraph, don't think community here likes reading a long story. Secondly, it will be great if you could show what is the error you're seeing in Xcode when your app "crashed" at splash screen. If you deploy your app directly from Xcode to a device, and it crashed in the Splash Screen, there has to be some error message showing you. Can you do a screenshot and upload here?

Comment: @TommyLeong Thank you for the edits. I will try to improve my way of questioning. And the app doesn't crash on the first launch it works fine on the first launch. But I will edit this and share the screenshot.

Comment: Is it actually stuck on the splash screen, or does it just take a long time to move past it? After updating my device to 14.6 the xcode debugger seems incredibly slow to attach, taking 2-3 minutes each time, during which the splash screen is shown. Have you tried waiting a few minutes to see if it moves past the splash screen and runs the app?

Comment: @Thijs No, the debugger doesn't start. The app completely froze once clicked on debug or reload.

Comment: ios device and metro cli must be in one wifi

Comment: @VasylNahuliak They are on the same wifi it is not related to that I have mentioned the cause of the issue at the end of the question please check that and if you have some suggestion please let me know.

Comment: I remember! I get same strange error. Long time try to fixed, but I dont how I do this. Only one idea it's about change wifi, example try use VPN or HotSpot. I get this bug when I change my physics location (change from for home to office).

Comment: @VasylNahuliak I am sure that it's not a network related issue. It is due to unsupported xcode and iOS versions.

Comment: Can you try: Open Xcode, then choose "Preferences..." from the Xcode menu. Go to the Locations panel and install the tools by selecting the most recent version in the Command Line Tools dropdown.

Comment: If you're using react-native-splash-screen, try not to display it from the native side. So that you can the error behind it.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal haven't used react-native-splash-screen. Getting the issue even on a new project.

Comment: first try to change build configuration to release in the Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and then make sure your phone and pc is on same wifi if you are connecting wirelessly. also try to check on your mac book privacy settings if you have accidentally turned on firewall and blocked all incoming connections. You need to turn that all off.

Comment: Probably, then you should post a screenshot of your error.

Comment: I catch this bug today on real device ios 14.6, this package https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project fix me an error

Answer (score 0):

Delete `main.jsbundle` in `ios` folder.

Generate new `main.jsbundle`

`react-native bundle --reset-cache --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle`

Answer (score 0):

The network to which the device is connected must be the same as the network to which the computer is connected; otherwise, hot reload does not occur.